# OpenEdX's Email tab missing from Instructor Dashboard?

Tags: openedx

In the `Instructor Dashboard` of our OpenEdX, the `Mail` tab is missing. This allows [bulk mailing to OpenEdx participants](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-partner-course-staff/en/latest/manage_live_course/bulk_email.html).

[image]

**How to enable the `Instructor Dashboard` > `Mail` functionality ?**

---

**Edit:** I though is would be a parameter in /lms/envs/common.py but it doesn't seems to be there. I noticed the test [./lms/djangoapps/bulk_email/tests/test_email.py#L198](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/c08010e5db54217f1b2866d3ca9e22558703cf8e/lms/djangoapps/bulk_email/tests/test_email.py#L198) with :

```
@patch.dict(settings.FEATURES, {'ENABLE_INSTRUCTOR_EMAIL': True, 'REQUIRE_COURSE_EMAIL_AUTH': False})
```

But [I didnt find any meaningful instances of it elsewhere](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/search?q=ENABLE_INSTRUCTOR_EMAIL&unscoped_q=ENABLE_INSTRUCTOR_EMAIL).

Answer (score 1):

The way you [configure bulk email has changed] in 2016. As of 2018, see `6.2. Changing the Bulk Email Setting` : http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/open-edx-release-notes/en/latest/bulk_email.html

On http://{your_URL}/admin > `Bulk email flags` > Add > Set it such :

[image]

And then :
[image]